# Google-Colab No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to access a dataset directly from my computer in Google Colab from a Youtube tutorial and I keep getting errors saying the file or directory doesn't exist. I've tried writing the path name differently, using '\' instead of '/', using r"...",copying the exact code from the tutorial and directly copying the path from properties and nothing works. I've found similar questions on SO but nothing that helps. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import cv2

DATADIR = "C:/Datasets/PetImages"
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]

for category in CATEGORIES:
  path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
  for img in os.listdir(path):
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
    break
  break
```

These are my errors:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-f8d293e3d38a> in <module>()
      9 for category in CATEGORIES:
     10   path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
---> 11   for img in os.listdir(path):
     12     img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
     13     plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Datasets/PetImages/Dog'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to upload your files first.

```
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
```

There are various ways to load the external data.  Please check this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

I got the solution by mounting the google drive in colab and then running the

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=0)
data
```

And it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps

1. Open the File dialog box from the left most vertical navigation pane in the Google Colab.
2. Look for three icons in the top row of this dialog box
3. click on the left most file upload icon
4. Choose the file in the file browse dialog box

With this solution, you have to upload a file everytime you open the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you did. Here is the solution that might be helpful!
Firstly, as you are using google colab, make sure to always load you dataset using these 3 lines of code. for that, upload the dataset(s) in you drive in a new folder. After that go to colab and type the first code. Then type the second code, you will be prompted to your Gmail website to verify. finally, look into the files section on the left side of your colab notebook, you'll see that your drive has been uploaded. Copy the dataset folder link and paste in into the data_dir variable and you are done.
1.`from google.colab import drive`
2.`drive.mount('/content/drive')`
3.`data_dir= '/content/drive/MyDrive/NewFolder'`

I hope your problem should be solved.